# Regex to find A and not B on a line

Tags: python, regex, textmate

I'm looking for a regex to search my python program to find all lines where `foo`, but not `bar`, is passed into a method as a keyword argument. I'm playing around with lookahead and lookbehind assertions, but not having much luck.

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you have a string `foo` that you want to find and another string `bar` that must not be present, you can use this:

```
^(?!.*bar).*foo
```

Creating a regular expression that exactly meets all your requirements is very difficult as Python code is not a regular language, but hopefully you should be able to use this as a starting point to get something good enough for your needs.

Comment: I'm fairly confident all the occurrences are on the same line, and if I miss some it doesn't matter. I just mentioned python to give some context.

Comment: @Zach, what Mark meant is that the string `bar` could occur without being a keyword (or did you mean identifier?): it could be inside a string literal or part of a comment.

Answer (score 5):

Having the `^` *after* the lookaheads in these scenarios always seems to work better for me. Reading it makes more sense to me, too.

`(?!.*bar)^.*foo`

```
this has a foo          # pass
so does this has a foo  # pass
i can haz foo           # pass
but i haz foo and bar!  # fail
```

Comment: Could you post a string that works "better" when placing the `^` after it instead of before?

Comment: Big props for this, python regex frustrating solved.  Was trying to find all files of a certain name but exclude any tilde backup files.  (?!.*~)^.*filename.ext

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this with not a regex:

```
for line in file:
    if "foo" in line and "bar" not in line:
        #do something
```

Comment: I'm searching through many files so it's much easier to just use a tool that takes a regular expression and handles the traversing of files for me. 

Thanks though

Comment: For sure. I love regexes and use them daily. It's just worth bearing in mind that sometimes, you should just tell the program exactly what you want and save yourself a headache. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Match whole line:

```
^(?=.*a)(?!.*b).*$
```