# posix regex to find A but no B in the same line

Tags: regex, posix

I know that perl compatible regex can do this easily by using the "lookaround" technology, but I only have posix regex on my hand which does not support the "lookaround", so my question is that can I find A but not B on a line only using posix regex.

Here is a simple example:

I want to find a "foo" but no "bar" on a line,

```
this has a foo           # match
i can haz foo            # match
but i haz foo and bar    # NOT match
```

**[and here is a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610581/regex-to-find-a-and-not-b-on-a-line)**

Comment: what tool or language do you use?

Comment: I think the solution can only be tailored for a particular case.

Comment: There seems to be this delusion that a sufficiently complex single regex match is somehow more efficient than two simple regex matches

Comment: or in any language something like `yourInput.contains("foo") && !yourInput.contains("bar")`

Comment: @Matt: Believing that two simple regex matches are more efficient is wrong too. There're no rules, only different situations.

Comment: @Casimir: True, but many regex newcomers don't even *think* of using separate regexes until someone suggests it.  I know *I* didn't.  Matt's comment may have been overly dramatic, but it was worth making.

Answer (score 0):

The best way (whatever the language or tool you use) is to test the two patterns (or the two strings) separately. Example with sed:

```
sed -n '/foo/{/bar/!p}'
```

It's short, simple and efficient.

To do the same with one ERE pattern, you must write:

```
^([^b]|b([^a]|$|a([^r]|$)))*foo([^b]|b([^a]|$|a([^r]|$)))*$
```

Do you think it's a better choice? *(and it is a three letters word)*